# Splitting article on multiple images

Tags: php, html, image

I got an article that is read from the database. Which is in a wrapper, I needed an image to be full width (so even wider than the wrapper) while still being in the article. So I split it on the image tag like the code below.

However this prevents a user from adding multiple images. When I add another image tag it doesn't show the image.

How can I split the article not just on one image but every image?

All data (text, img tags) is in 'introtext'.

For example:

```
<p>Part one of the article</p>
//Here the article is split on all img tags that are there.
<img src="#">
<img src="#">
<img src="#">
<img src="#">
<p>Part two of the article</p>
```

The below code only works when I add one image tag.

```
<div class="container relative" style="padding: 0px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
             <div class="blog-item mb-20 mb-xs-40">
                <!-- Text -->
                <div class="blog-item-body">
                    <? 
                        $introtext = $contenti[0]['introtext'];

                        $splitartikel = preg_split('/(<img[^>]+\>)/i', $introtext, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

                        echo $splitartikel[0];

                    ?>      
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid relative" style="padding: 0px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="middleimage">
                <?
                    echo $splitartikel[1];
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="container relative" style="padding: 0px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
             <div class="blog-item mb-20 mb-xs-40">
                <!-- Text -->
                <div class="blog-item-body">
                    <? 
                        echo $splitartikel[2];
                    ?>      
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The query:

```
// Articles
    $content    = "SELECT * FROM `lb_content` WHERE alias = '".$conn->real_escape_string($_GET['alias'])."' ";
    $contentcon = $conn->query($content);
    $contenti   = array();
    while ($contenti[] = $contentcon->fetch_array());
```

I also tried looping the middle part, but this also loops the text before and after the image, while I only want to have the option to have multiple images.

Like this:

```
<?php foreach($splitartikel as $part) : ?>
<div class="container-fluid relative" style="padding: 0px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="middleimage">
                <?php echo $part; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Maybe I need to do some sort of foreach loop for every image tag?

Comment: what is the array that you are passing to this page? Please post full code.

Comment: Added it, not sure why it would be needed though.